# pwa has different background on mobile device

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I have a strange problem, when I launch my WPA in developing mode on my computer it has a white background, but if I launch it on my android  phone after installing it on the device, it appears with a black background; so I think there is  a setting in my phone that I do not know